# AngularJS: Change route before a redirect countdown runs out but the redirect starts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, countdown

I have got a problem with a simple login/logout page. When a user logs in/out, a success message with a countdown is shown. When the timout expires, the route changes.

However, the user can navigate before the countdown ends (using the menu or a button). The problem is that even when using the menu, the login/-out timeout still fires.

Here the code of the counter:

```
$scope.onTimeout = function(){
        $scope.counter--;
        $scope.timeoutCountdown = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
        if($scope.counter === -1){
            $scope.safeApply(function() { $location.path("/home"); }); //if the user isn't logged...redirect to main
        }
};
```

And this is the code that change the location when press the button:

```
$scope.redirectToHome = function() {
        $scope.safeApply(function() { $location.path("/portale"); });

};
```

Does anybody know why the timeout fires after changing the controller?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Specify 'a bad effect'. What exactly is going wrong? In its current form, your question is very hard to understand.

Comment: I know. And it's very difficult to explain :-). The effect is that when a user goes to home route using the button and then changes the route going, for example, in the search route...the countdown runs out and changes the route with home again.

Comment: So basically you'd want to cancel the timeout if the user changes the route before the timeout is expired?

Comment: Yes. It's not so long that I use angularJS but I don't understand: I thought the previous $scope/Controller would die when you change the route. But I was wrong or is there something that I miss?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your clarification. I added an answer, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is due to the fact the timeout is not cleared when the $scope is destroyed.

You need to manually clear the timeout by listening to the `$destroy` event. This event originates from Angular and is thrown whenever a $scope is destroyed. Try adding the following to your controller (I did not test this, so consider this pseudo code)

```
$scope.$watch('$destroy', function(){
    $timeout.cancel($scope.timeoutCountdown);
});
```

Edit:

You could also do this right before changing the route:

```
$scope.redirectToHome = function() {
    $timeout.cancel($scope.timeoutCountdown);
    $scope.safeApply(function() { $location.path("/portale"); });
};
```

Just keep in mind that if you have other redirect possibilities (i.e. other buttons the user could use to navigate from the login/-out page), you'd need to do this for each of those (or preferably wrap it in a method).

Comment: First at all: thanks! It seems the right way but it still doesn't work. I have added a console.log on your 'watch' and it prints when the controller takes the control and it doesn't print when I change the route with the button.

Comment: That means the controller is not destroyed when the route is changed. Could you update your question and add the part of your code where you're setting the new route?

Comment: Done! But it's very simple: I change the location.

Comment: Hmm, could you possibly create a plunkr (http://plnkr.co/) for this. I'll be happy to debug it for you, but it's hard to tell what's wrong from this point.

Comment: Ok but I'm at work so it'll take some hours. However, if I do the cancel before change the location, will it fix the problem in your opinion?

Comment: That should work as well, I updated my answer. If that does not suit your needs, then take your time to put it in a plunkr. I'm currently at work myself so no problem :)

Comment: Brilliant! Incredibly helpful.